# Is it possible to add the (.as) actionscript file dynamically in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Am developing application in flex which is loaded the action script file .

```
<DrawingArea id="drawingArea"   xmlns="*" width="100%" height="100%" add="drawingArea_addHandler(event)"/>
```

i need to add it dynamically,how to do this ?guide me

**update**
This is my Drawing area how to create `var da:DrawingArea=new DrawingArea`
how to access the listener function?
    public function DrawingArea()
        {
            super();

```
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, function(event:FlexEvent):void {
            erase();
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            x1 = mouseX;
            y1 = mouseY;
            isDrawing = true;
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            if (!event.buttonDown)
            {
                isDrawing = false;
            }

            x2 = mouseX;
            y2 = mouseY;
            if (isDrawing)
            {
                graphics.lineStyle(2, drawColor);
                graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
                graphics.lineTo(x2, y2);
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
            }
        });

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
            isDrawing = false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamically? The .as file needs to be added after or before compiling the application?

Comment: @At Jevgenij Dmitrijev run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made changes to your code.

```
package
    {
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        public class DrawingArea
        {
            private var _target:UIComponent;

            private var _x1:Number;
            private var _y1:Number;

            private var _x2:Number;
            private var _y2:Number;

            [Bindable]
            private var _isDrawing:Boolean = false;

            private var _drawColor:uint = 0xFFFF00

            public function DrawingArea(target:UIComponent)
            {
                //TODO: implement function
                _target = target
                _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, downEvent, false, 0, true);
                _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, upEvent, false, 0, true);
                _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, upEvent, false, 0, true);
            }

            private function downEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                _x1 = event.localX;
                _y1 = event.localY;
                _isDrawing = true;

                _target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveEvent, false, 0, true);
            }

            private function moveEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (!event.buttonDown)
                {
                    _isDrawing = false;
                }

                _x2 = event.localX;
                _y2 = event.localY;
                if (_isDrawing)
                {
                    _target.graphics.lineStyle(2, _drawColor);
                    _target.graphics.moveTo(_x1, _y1);
                    _target.graphics.lineTo(_x2, _y2);
                    _x1 = _x2;
                    _y1 = _y2;
                }

            }

            private function upEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                _isDrawing = false;

                _target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveEvent);
            }

            public function set drawColor(value:uint): void{
                _drawColor = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

Created a class DrawingAreaView.mxml in which, created object for DrawingArea and passed the class itself as container.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns="components.*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
           creationComplete="onInit();">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import components.DrawingArea;

            private var drawingArea:DrawingArea;

            private function onInit():void {
                drawingArea = new DrawingArea(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Use above class in Application.

```
<DrawingAreaView id="drawingArea" width="100%" height="100%"/>

or

private var _drawingAreaView:DrawingAreaView = new DrawingAreaView();

parentObject.addChild(_drawingAreaView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to load a file in memory and then execute it, if that is what you want, in Acionscript. However, what you can do is create a `DrawingArea` (or any other element) at run-time based on some event (such as user click or a specific timeout period).

Comment: my drawingArea is separate class that extends uicomponent,how to  DrawingArea (or any other element) at run-time?

Comment: By creating a new object using something like `new DrawingArea()`. You can also take a look at the `getDefintionByName` function to create an instance by passing in a class name.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your functions are defined inline. Till you dont give them names it will be impossible anyway.
i would suggest

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownFunction);
public function mouseDownFunction(event:MouseEvent = null ):void {
        x1 = mouseX;
        y1 = mouseY;
        isDrawing = true;
    }
```

Then they should become accesable via the object. DrawingArea.mouseDownFunction()